# Xcode couldn't find header file although it's added into the header search paths

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, header

I have a third party library OpenMVG that I want to use in my project LatchAid. The OpenMVG has been built and installed. Its headers live in /usr/local/include/openMVG and /usr/local/include/openMVG_dependencies.

In the project settings of my Xcode project, I have added /usr/local/include into Header Search Paths. However, when I used 
import  in my code and compile, I get the following error:
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group
/Users/chendavies/Documents/LatchAid/LatchAid/LatchAidWrapper.h:17:13: 'openMVG/sfm/sfm.hpp' file not found

I don't understand why this would happen, since if the header search path has been setup properly, it should be able to find the file located at:
/usr/local/include/openMVG/sfm/sfm.hpp

I have been stuck with this for a little while and have tried to make the header search path (/usr/local/include) recursive and non-recursive. I have also tried to use the combination of /usr/local/include/openMVG as the header search path and import the path of sfm/sfm.hpp
with the same error. I have looked for the answer online but couldn't find any direct answers that fix my issue.

Any thoughts and insights on why this is happening? Have I missed something? My Xcode version is 9.3. Thanks a lot for your help and information!

Comment: In the file `LatchAidWrapper.h` look for a reference to `openMVG/sfm/sfm.hpp`, that's likely the issue.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean? I have the #import<openMVG/sfm/sfm.hpp> inside the LatchAidWrapper.h file. This file lives in /usr/local/include/openMVG/sfm/. So if my header search path is set to be /usr/local/include it should be able to find the header file, right?

Comment: Do you make similar references in any other headers? Are you using `-I/usr/local/include` in the header search paths, or set as a flag? Also if that file lives where you say it does why does the path show as `/Users/chendavies/Documents/LatchAid/LatchAid/LatchAidWrapper.h`?

Comment: Inside the Header Search Paths, I entered /usr/local/include and choose to be non-recursive. Excuse my confusion, I don't quite get what you mean: /Users/chendavies/Documents/LatchAid/LatchAid/LatchAidWrapper.h is a header file of my own project and shouldn't be related to the header search paths?

Comment: What I mean is the error in your questions shows the file `LatchAidWrapper.h` as being in the path described in my last comment, not in the one you mention in the comment above that.